# JAVA - ¿Divisores de un numero decimal?

Tags: java

Tengo este código que calcula los divisores de un numero int, ejemplo 12:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        if (T % i == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Pero quiero calcular los divisores de un numero float/double, ejemplo: 4.5

Se puede hacer eso?

Comment: Hablando de la matemática, antes que de la programación, tengo la duda, ¿Cuáles serían los divisores de 4.5?

Comment: Pues por ejemplo 1.5, que me da 3, has de cuenta que quiero hallar los multiplicadores o divisores, porque supongamos que 4.5 es el area por ejemplo, entonces si hallo los divisores y luego multiplico uno por 1 me dan el area, no se si me explico

Comment: No, no realmente. A lo que voy, dicho en otras palabras, es a que el término _divisor_ que utilizas, para números con fracciones, no existe como tal. Creo que tu pregunta debe incluir una definición clara de las propiedades que debe tener los números que _tu requerimiento particular_ considera _divisores_ de un número con decimales. Sin esta descripción precisa, no hay nadie en la tierra que pueda escribir un algoritmo para hallarlos.